# How can rewrite function instead of reference?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

```
var BigObject = (function() {

  function deepCalculate(a, b, c) {
    return a + b + c;
  }

  function calculate(x) {
    deepCalculate(x, x, x);
  }

  return {
    calculate: calculate,
    api: {        
      deepCalculate: deepCalculate
    }
  }
})();
```

This is basic self executing function with private function I keep in `api`.
The problem I have is that now I can't overwrite `deepCalculate` from the outside of the function.

How is that a problem? I use `Jasmine` and want to test if function was called. For example:

```
spyOn(BigObject, 'calculate').andCallThrough();
expect(BigObject.api.deepCalculate).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

fails. However as I debug, I am sure that Jasmine binds `BigObject.api.deepCalculate` as a spy, however from the inside calculate still calls original `deepCalculate` function and not the spy.

I would like to know how can I overwrite the function and not just a reference for it.

Comment: You are missing a closing curly brace in the last line.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't make any difference. It's just for example purposes

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer would be:

```
(function ()
{
    var overWriteMe = function(foo)
    {
        return foo++;
    },
    overWrite = function(newFunc)
    {
        for (var p io returnVal)
        {
            if (returnVal[p] === overWriteMe)
            {//update references
                returnVal[p] = newFunc;
                break;
            }
        }
        overWriteMe = newFunc;//overwrite closure reference
    },
    returnVal = {
        overWrite: overWrite,
        myFunc: overWriteMe
    };
}());
```

Though I must say that, I'd seriously think about alternative ways to acchieve whatever it is you're trying to do. A closure, IMO, should be treated as a whole. Replacing parts of it willy-nilly will soon prove to be a nightmare: you don't know what the closure function will be at any given point in time, where it was changed, what the previous state was, and why it was changed. 
A temporary sollution might just be this:

```
var foo = (function()
{
    var calc = function(x, callback)
    {
        callback = callback || defaultCall;
        return callback.apply(this, [x]);
    },
    defaultCall(a)
    {
        return a*a+1;
    },
    return {calc: calc};
}());
foo(2);//returns 5
foo(2,function(x){ return --x;});//returns 1
foo(2);//returns 5 again
```

IMO, this is a lot safer, as it allows you to choose a different *"internal"* function to be used once, without changing the core behaviour of the code.